# type conversion PTLib PString -> std::string

Tags: c++

How??
In documentation of PTLib:

> PString::operator std::string     () const [inline]
>
> Cast the PString to a std::string.

I try:

```
m_string= string(m_pstring);
m_string = (string) m_pstring;
```

But get 
error: call of overloaded 'basic_string(PString&)' is ambiguous

gcc version 4.6.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
m_string = m_pstring.operator std::string();
```

Comment: @Meysam Can't test it since I am not using PTLib, but I guess it's because PString has another conversion operator and std::string has multiple constructors, some other combination might match as well so its ambiguous.